# Grid view,negative values checked and disabled

Tags: c#, gridview, foreach, grid

I have a grid,in this grid I check if the value is less than zero,is yes I need to have it checked and can't be unselected.The logic is working but I can't update the grid.

```
foreach (GridViewRow grdDisable in grdSimulacao.Rows)
                {
                   // CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) grdDisable.FindControl("chkSeleciona");

                    if (double.Parse(grdDisable.Cells[5].Text) < 0)
                    {
                        ((CheckBox)grdDisable.FindControl("chkSeleciona")).Checked = true;
                        ((CheckBox) grdDisable.FindControl("chkSeleciona")).Enabled = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ((CheckBox)grdDisable.FindControl("chkSeleciona")).Checked = false;
                    }

                }
```

But when I open the application,the first value is the only less than 0,but it opens normally.I need to have it selected and cant remove the checked.Someone knows what I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: On wich event this code takes place? How do you bind your grid ? why not using a biding for this ?

Comment: I was using dataBind,but i had two dataBind,somehow it was having a conflict i think,when i delete one of them,the code started working.